# Can I "transpose" a list of maps into a map of lists in Clojure?

Tags: list, dictionary, clojure, transpose

Hi huys : I want to map a "average" for all values in a map.  say I have a list of maps :

```
[{"age" 2 "height" 1 "weight" 10},
{"age" 4 "height" 4 "weight" 20},
{"age" 7 "height" 11 "weight" 40}]
```

And my desired output is

```
{"age 5 "height" 5 ....}
```

///Below are the ramblings of my brain, i.e. the way I might imagine this working in Clojure...not to be taken too seriously

transpose the list :

```
  {"age" [2 4 7] "height" [1 4 11] }
```

and then I could simply do something like (again, making up a function called freduce here)

```
  (freduce average (vals (map key-join list)))
```

to get

`{"age" 5 "weight" 10 "height" 7}`

Comment: You are going to want to reduce so that you don't have to traverse the sequence twice. You will start with an empty map as your accumulator and as your reduce gets to each map, sum all of the values with the corresponding values in the accumulator. On the last element of the list divide each value by the length of the list.

Comment: I actually want to do more sophisticated mathematics on the data (standard deviation, ...), so Im thinking that I want to decouple the way the data is merged from the way it is transposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fairly verbose solution. Hopefully someone can come up with something better:

```
(let [maps [{"age" 2 "height" 1 "weight" 10},
            {"age" 4 "height" 4 "weight" 20},
            {"age" 7 "height" 11 "weight" 40}]
      ks (keys (first maps))
      series-size (count maps)
      avgs (for [k ks]
             (/ (reduce +
                        (for [m maps]
                          (get m k)))
                series-size))]
  (zipmap ks avgs))
```

Comment: Yours is the correct solution, I think, in that it is very readable.

Answer (score 6):

Create the map of vectors:

```
(reduce (fn [m [k v]]
          (assoc m k (conj (get m k []) v)))
        {}
        (apply concat list-of-maps))
```

Create the map of averages:

```
(reduce (fn [m [k v]]
          (assoc m k (/ (reduce + v) (count v))))
        {}
        map-of-vectors)
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [merge-with](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/merge-with)

Here's my go at some actual code:

```
(let [maps [{"age" 2 "height" 1 "weight" 10},
            {"age" 4 "height" 4 "weight" 20},
            {"age" 7 "height" 11 "weight" 40}]]
  (->> (apply merge-with #(conj %1 %2)
             (zipmap (apply clojure.set/union (map keys maps))
                     (repeat [])) ; set the accumulator
             maps)
       (map (fn [[k v]] [k (/ (reduce + v) (count v))]))
       (into {})))
```

Comment: This is elegant but probably a little too advanced for me at this point.  Thanks for pointing me towards merge-with I will learn it...

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn key-join [map-list]
  (let [keys (keys (first map-list))]
       (into {} (for [k keys] [k (map #(% k) map-list)]))))
(defn mapf [f map]
  (into {} (for [[k v] map ] [k (f v)])))
(defn average [col]
  (let [n (count col)
        sum (apply + col)]
       (/ sum n)))
```

**DEMO**

```
user=> (def data-list [{"age" 2 "height" 1 "weight" 10},
{"age" 4 "height" 4 "weight" 20},
{"age" 7 "height" 11 "weight" 40}])
#'user/data-list
user=> (key-join data-list)
{"age" (2 4 7), "height" (1 4 11), "weight" (10 20 40)}
user=> (mapf average (key-join data-list))
{"age" 13/3, "height" 16/3, "weight" 70/3}
```

Comment: Seems to make sense.  Not sure where the average is applied ... mapf i guess >?

Comment: Rewriting of such arbitrarily's good if you're saying that if the function name.

Comment: >Not sure where the average is applied. average is applied map-data value(Collection). "average" would not have applied to the map-key.Let alone, reduce(!) average map-data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version that uses merge-with without zipmap.

```
(let [data [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 2 :b 4} {:a 4 :b 8}]
           num-vals (count data)]
     (->> data (apply merge-with +) 
          (reduce (fn [m [k v]] (assoc m k (/ v num-vals))) {})))
```

Comment: This assumes all keys are present in all maps, which may be an unfounded assumption (it's not explicit, at least).

Comment: you're right on the keys assumption, if some maps were missing keys you would need to replace the `+` in merge-with with `#(+ (or %1 0) (or %2 0))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my one-liner solution:

```
(def d [{"age" 2 "height" 1 "weight" 10},
   {"age" 4 "height" 4 "weight" 20},
   {"age" 7 "height" 11 "weight" 40}])

(into {} (map (fn [[k v] [k (/ v (count d))]]) (apply merge-with + d)))

=> {"height" 16/3, "weight" 70/3, "age" 13/3}
```

Logics as follows:

- Use merge-with + on the maps to calculate a sum for each key value
- Divide all the resulting values by the total number of maps to get an average
- Put the results back in a hashmap with (into {} ...)